# WPF, XAML: CustomControl like TextBox with caption

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

My attempt to create a **CustomControl** like a **TextBox** with variable **caption**.

I try to learn create CustomControl and my exceptation is that my CustomControl (I called it **TextBoxCustomControl**) has every properties and methods of TextBox and also has new property *Caption*.

I hope that is right, that my **TextBoxCustomControl** is inherited from **TextBox** and not from **Control**.

---

**TextBoxCustomControl.cs**

```
namespace CustomControlProject
{
    public class TextBoxCustomControl : TextBox
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Caption", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(String.Empty));

        public string Caption
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CaptionProperty, value); }
        }

        static TextBoxCustomControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextBoxCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TextBoxCustomControl)));
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Themes\Generic.xaml** (specific design for **TextBoxCustomControl**) -- there is the TextBox called **innerTextBox**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControlProject">


    <Style x:Name="CustomStyle" TargetType="local:TextBoxCustomControl" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TextBoxCustomControl}">
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBox x:Name="innerTextBox" />
                        <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Caption}" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

---

In **MainWindow.xaml** I use my **TextBoxCustomControl** and specific some properties for it.

```
<Window x:Class="CustomControlProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControlProject"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <WrapPanel>
        <local:TextBoxCustomControl Width="287" Background="Yellow" Caption="Fill the nickname, please." />
    </WrapPanel>
</Window>
```

---

My expectation is that innerTextBox inside my TextBoxCustomControl inherit all properties (such like background, width, etc.), but that is not happened. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there's a difference between a CustomControl, inheriting from a Control, and an UserControl composed out of several Controls.

The Style you're applying is overriding all the TextBox's properties. When you set a Template, you need to use TemplateBinding for all the properties that you want to bind against later. If not, they will be no longer accessible from the outside.

For what you're trying to achieve, you can skip the Style and change XAML to

```
<Window x:Class="CustomControlProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControlProject"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:TextBoxCustomControl 
            x:Name="CustomBox" 
            Width="287" Background="Yellow" 
            Caption="Fill the nickname, please." />
        <Label 
            Content="{Binding ElementName=CustomBox, Path=Caption}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

To make it all-in-one, you'd need to build a UserControl.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, what you are making is a composite control. So, inheriting it from `TextBox` doesn't make any sense. Inheriting from `TextBox` would make sense if you are improving a normal `TextBox` with additional capabilities.
2. Your thinking that whatever you set at your custom control level will be inherited by child controls is wrong. If you want to do that, use `TemplateBinding` for individual `properties`. Eg; `<TextBox x:Name="innerTextBox" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>` .

   Note : Some properties (FontSize, FontFamily) are propagated anutomatically without any extra work.
3. What you are trying to make is already present as `<HeaderedContentControl/>` . You can study its source code [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/HeaderedContentControl.cs,996e11e6f21c1c3a) or using ILSpy.

Sample :

```
    <HeaderedContentControl>
        <HeaderedContentControl.Header>
            <Border>
                <TextBlock Text="Name please !"/>
            </Border>
        </HeaderedContentControl.Header>
        <HeaderedContentControl.Content>
            <TextBox />
        </HeaderedContentControl.Content>
    </HeaderedContentControl>
```